# Firestore query by multi-level 'back pointer'?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We are having a lot of trouble finding an efficient way to handle the following problem in Cloud Firestore and would greatly appreciate any and all suggestions!

We have a deep hierarchical tree where let's say there are documents A, B, C, and D. A contains some Bs, which contain Cs, which contain Ds. Each document has fields for its child collection as well as a reference "back pointer" to its parent in the tree. So you can go down the tree like A.B.C.D, and then you can also get back up the tree to A by conceptually going D.C.B.A.

The problem that we are having is that we need to efficiently query for "all Ds in A". Ideally, we would be able to do something conceptually like `select all D where D.C.B.A = 'some A'`.

What is the best way to handle this efficiently? We are willing to get hack-ish if necessary at this point, because this is a core-use use case for our app, and we have not found any workable solution yet in Cloud Firestore.

We are having a lot of trouble finding an efficient way to handle the following problem in Cloud Firestore and would greatly appreciate any and all suggestions!

We have a deep hierarchical tree where let's say there are documents A, B, C, and D. A contains some Bs, which contain Cs, which contain Ds. Each document has fields for its child collection as well as a reference "back pointer" to its parent in the tree. So you can go down the tree like A.B.C.D, and then you can also get back up the tree to A by conceptually going D.C.B.A.

The problem that we are having is that we need to efficiently query for "all Ds in A". Ideally, we would be able to do something conceptually like `select all D where D.C.B.A = 'some A'`.

What is the best way to handle this efficiently? We are willing to get hack-ish if necessary at this point, because this is a core-use use case for our app, and we have not found any workable solution yet in Cloud Firestore.

Sorry for the overlay generalized alphabet soup. Our data model is pretty large and complex, and I was trying to avoid getting into the weeds (and posting code/model that I'm not allowed to). But I can at least give a better analogy. This geographical model pseudo code is pretty analogous to our use case:

```
class Country
{
    List<State> states;
    President currentPresident;
}

class State
{
    List<City> cities;
    Country parentCountry;
    string governor;
}

class City
{
    List<Person> persons;
    State parentState;
    string mayor;
}

class Person
{
    City city;
    string name;
}
```

We then need to be able to run queries like:
- "Get all the people that live in Country X"
- "Get all the people living in a City governed by Mayor Y"

The ideal would be to be able to say "select all Person where City.State.Country == 'someCountry'".

We realize that we can flatten the references into Person. But we have a large (and potentially increasing) number of references used to "slice and dice" Persons by different criteria. And if there are tens or hundreds of millions of Persons (as is the case in our real database), then all of those flattened references do not seem efficient. And in our analogy, something like State or Country would not be just a string or simple object, it would have many fields, which could potentially be used to 
filter Persons.

We are wide open to reorganizing our model if it means better Firestore performance as long as it doesn't mean completely breaking the intuitive and maintainable organization of the data.

Thanks again for your thoughts!

Comment: Instead of describing your database structure, please add a screenshot of it, to see it more clearly.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/FeLKJG5dhHc/T5FKdstsAgAJ

Comment: Additional detail added to the original post and to the Google group as well. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

> "We then need to be able to run queries like:
>   - "Get all the people that live in Country X"
>   - "Get all the people living in a City governed by Mayor Y""

What about remodel it like this,

Create many `Person` Collections called:

```
- PersonCity
- PersonCountry
- PersonState
```

I think flattening is the key here and space in the cloud is cheap right.
Then when creating a person one must double save some data

Another thought is this like depending on the query complexity like if the query contains only one field or many, Create `Collections` like this

```
- PersonQueryOneField
   - Name "oskar"
   - City "miami"


- PersonQueryTwoField
   - Name "oskar"
   - City "miami"
   - Country "usa"


- PersonQueryThreeField
   - Name "oskar"
   - City  "miami"
   - Country "usa"
   - State "florida"

- PersonQueryTenField
   - Name "oskar"
   - City  "miami"
   - Country "usa"
   - State "florida"
   - Age   "7"
   - Length "98cm"
   - Gender "boy"
   - Extra1  "na"
   - Extra2  "na"
   - Extra3  "na"
```

Maybe a majority of the queries on `PersonQueryTwoField` then it will be cheaper faster to get the data,

Space is cheap!

Just an ide!

Comment: That's an interesting idea. We'll have to think about that some. In our case, the equivalent of Person is high volume (tens or hundreds of millions of "rows"), so even with cheap storage, that still seems a little scary. But we will definitely consider all options. Thanks!